# node async wait unable to understand this behaviour

Tags: node.js

Curious to know why async/await does not work in the case below ?

What do you think i am doing wrong.

conn is an async function and an async function is a promise which can be chained no ?

```
const db = require('oracledb');

const conn = async () => {
  return await db.getConnection({user: "my_user",
    password: "my_pass",
    connectString: "dbserver/dbservice"
  });
}
undefined

> conn
[AsyncFunction: conn]

conn.execute('select sysdate from dual').then((result) => {
  console.log(results.row);
});
```

I get an error why ?

```
ypeError: conn.execute is not a function
   at repl:1:6
   at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:50:33)
   at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:240:29)
   at bound (domain.js:301:14)
   at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:314:12)
   at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:441:10)
   at emitOne (events.js:121:20)
   at REPLServer.emit (events.js:211:7)
   at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:282:10)
   at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:631:8)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of an async function is indeed a promise. But you can't chain anything to a promise — you can chain functions that promises have such as `then()` and `catch()`. Additionally, you need to call `conn()` which will return a promise result rather than chaining off the function itself.

You should do something like:

```
conn()
.then(connection => connection.execute('select sysdate from dual'))
.then(result => console.log(results.row))
```

*note: I'm not sure what the oracledb api passes from `getConnection()` I'm guessing it's an object to make further calls.*